# What linux kernel does amdgpu-pro 17.50 work with

Tags: 16.04, kernel, amdgpu-pro

My linux computer won't boot unless I go in recovery mode. When I boot I see a graphical glitch, the screen goes black and the GPU fans speed up. The GPU I'm using is from the Radeon r9 300 series. The distro version is Ubuntu 16.04. It still doesn't boot even when I remove the drivers.

Comment: Seem like a good question for AMD. Have you read the release notes?

Comment: I read it and I couldn't find anything

Comment: Do the new drivers always work for the oldest kernels first?

Comment: No, probably not, as said above, you have to ask AMD which kernel to use with the specific driver version. Here is something similar, ...was very easy to find: https://community.amd.com/thread/221840